# AS3 - ByteArray to bitmap

Tags: actionscript-3, arrays

I encoded an image to a ByteArray. How to convert it to a bitmap from that ByteArray? 
Thanks. Uli

Answer (score 2):

I did this test below which works well. It converts a Bytearray to Bitmap. The format of the image is irrelevant. png, jpg, gif all hold their format in the meta data which the bitmapdata class will interpret for you. You should use JPEGEncoder or PNGEncoder when saving.

```
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        public var _file:File;
        public var _stream:FileStream;
        public var _load:Loader;

        protected function init(event:FlexEvent):void {
            _file = File.desktopDirectory;
            _file.addEventListener( Event.SELECT, selectComplete);
            _file.browseForOpen( 'Image' );
        }
        private function selectComplete( event:Event ):void {
            _stream = new FileStream();
            _stream.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, loadComplete );
            _stream.openAsync( _file, FileMode.READ );
        }
        private function loadComplete( event:Event ):void {
            var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
            _stream.readBytes( ba );
            _load = new Loader();
            _load.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, loadbytesComplete );
            _load.loadBytes( ba );
        }
        private function loadbytesComplete( event:Event ):void {
            var bit:Bitmap = _load.content as Bitmap;
            img.source = bit;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the format of your `ByteArray`? If the pixels are in 32-bit ARGB format, you can create a new `BitmapData` object and set the pixels using `BitmapData.setPixels()`. Then just assign the bitmap data to a bitmap object.

If they are not in 32-bit ARGB format, you will probably need to convert them first.

Comment: Interesting. How do I find out which format my ByteArray has? (The ByteArray is an image and contains also metadata info)

Comment: Also edit your question to include what your higher level goal is, it sounds like you might be doing something more complicated than you need to do to get these images loaded.

Comment: The image file format is JPEG. My higher level goal is to take the ByteArray and save it in different sizes to hard drive as JPEG.

Answer (score 0):

Use Loader

```
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.display.LoaderInfo;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.BitmapData;
 
private function startLoad():void
{
  var loader:Loader = new Loader();
  loader.loadBytes(byteArray);
  loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderComplete);
}     

private function loaderComplete(event:Event):void
{
    var loaderInfo:LoaderInfo = LoaderInfo(event.target);
    var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(loaderInfo.width, loaderInfo.height, false, 0xFFFFFF);
    bitmapData.draw(loaderInfo.loader);
    // result: bitmapData
}
```

Comment: I tried your code and all images I saved with it are invalid. I added this code below _draw_ to save the image to drive: `this.fileReference = new FileReference();
this.fileReference.save(bitmapData,"test.jpg" ); Any ideas why the images invalid? 
`

Answer (score 0):

this class can help you:
http://code.google.com/p/as3asclublib/source/browse/trunk/display/image/PNGDecoder.as?spec=svn123&r=123

Answer (score 0):

```
[Bindable]
private static var m_barrLogo:ByteArray;
.
.
.
private function init_m_barrLogo():void
{
    m_barrLogo = someValue;

    // The Image below will automatically read the new value of the ByteArray and
    // display the appropriate image.
}
.
.
.
<mx:Image source="{m_barrLogo}" y="10" x="10" scaleContent="true" height="140"
        width="145"/>
```